A continuous map between covering spaces is a covering map
I am learning Algebraic Topology with lack of topology knowledge. If someone could help me with the following question, that would be great! I am having a difficulty with the following theorem/fact:

Let $(\tilde{X}_1, p_1)$ and $(\tilde{X}_2,p_2)$ be covering spaces of $X$. Suppose $\tilde{X}_2$ is path-connected and $f\colon \tilde{X}_1 \to \tilde{X}_2$ be a continuous map such that $p_2\circ f = p_1$. Then, $f$ is a covering map from $\tilde{X}_1$ to $\tilde{X}_2$.

This is can also be found in Lemma 6.7 of Massey's book. I understand that $f$ is surjective because of path-connectedness. My confusion comes when showing $f$ is a covering map. Let $\tilde{x}_2 \in \tilde{X}_2$. And let $x = p_2(\tilde{x}_2)$. There exists $\tilde{x}_1\in \tilde{X}_1$ such that $f(\tilde{x}_1) = \tilde{x}_2$ by surjectivity. We can take an open neighbourhood $U \subset X$ (where $x\in U$) that is elementary open neighbourhood for both coverings. So we have $V\subset \tilde{X}_1$ which maps homeomorphically to $U$ and $\tilde{x}_1\in V$, and also we have $W \subset \tilde{X}_2$ which maps homeomorphically to $U$ and $\tilde{x}_2\in W$. And then I need to prove that $f$ restricted to $V$ is a local homeomorphism onto $W$. What is not clear to me is that why $f(V) = W$. Or why even $f(V) \subseteq W$? What if there is an element $v\in V$ such that $f(v) \in W'$ where $W'$ is another sheet (i.e. $W \cap W' = \emptyset$) in $\tilde{X}_2$ that is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$?
I guess this should not be possible, and the map $f$ restricted to $V$ is indeed a homeomorphism between $V$ and $W$, but I am not sure how to prove this. Do I need to another assumption about the spaces, e.g. locally connected or something else?
EDIT: I think if we add the assumption that $X$ is locally connected, there will be no problem. Because: $X$ is locally connected, so we may take $U \subset X$ to be a connected open set. Then, $V\subset \tilde{X}_1$ and $W \subset \tilde{X}_2$ are both connected open sets. $f(V) \subseteq \bigsqcup W_i$, where $W_i$ is a sheet that maps homeomorphically $U$ via $p_2$. Since $f$ is continuous $f(V)$ is connected and so there is exactly one sheet such that $f(V)$ is mapped onto, and it has to be $W$ because $\tilde{x}_1 \mapsto \tilde{x}_2 \in W$. I found that Munkres Lemma 80.2. uses this argument as well because the spaces in Munkres Chapter 13 are all locally path connected and path connected.
Now, my question is, does the theorem still work without assuming $X$ being locally connected or locally path connected?

Why not take $W$ to be the whole preimage of $U$ instead of just a sheet?

@Exitpath, then $W$ will not be homeomorphic to $V$? Because $W$ is a union of disjoint sheets, and $V$ is just one sheet. We may take $V$ being a union of sheets, but then I think the preimage of $W$ will not be disjoint union of sheets.
